# How to render points from CartoDB with Leaflet and Leaflet Vector Layers?

Tags: leaflet, carto

I have a table in [CartoDB](http://cartodb.com) containing some points. I want to render these points dynamically with Leaflet. There is cartodb.js for such tasks, but it does not support full customization of Tooltips, as I have seen. Instead I found a [Leaflet-Plugin](http://geojason.info/leaflet-vector-layers/demos/cartodb/) for that.

In my HTML I have the following JS-Code, but it does not work except showing the Base Map. What am I doing wrong? Are there other solutions for Leaflet?

```
var map = new L.Map('map').setView([51.0, 10.0], 6);
var defaultLayer = L.TileLayer.provider('MapQuestOpen.OSM');
map.addLayer(defaultLayer);

var baseLayers = {
"Mapquest OSM": defaultLayer,
"OpenStreetMap German Style": L.TileLayer.provider('OpenStreetMap.DE'),
    };

// Use Leaflet Vector Layers plugin to show data from CartoDB

var cartodblayer = new lvector.CartoDB({
    user: "user",
    table: "example_data",
    scaleRange: [6, 20],
    symbology: {
        vectorOptions: {
            icon: new customIcon({
                iconUrl: "/icon/icon.png"
            })
        }
    },
    popupTemplate: '<p>{homepage}</p>',
    singlePopup: false
});

cartodblayer.setMap(map);

map.addControl(new L.Control.Layers(baseLayers, '', {collapsed: true}));
```

Comment: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/develop/examples/leaflet.html

Comment: as I am working with @leak_my_brain: I have written an article about this: http://www.digital-geography.com/cartodb-and-leaflet-consuming-the-table-or-part-two/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can query cartoDB to get the points in GeoJSON format like this:

http://{account}.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM {table_name}

You will get a featurecollection looking something similar to this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":    {"cartodb_id":58,"name":xxx,"email":xxx,"created_at":"2011-03-20T09:44:38Z","updated_at":"2011-09-09T12:39:42Z","ncuser":1311468667},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[8.705274,50.607916]}},...
```

then you parse that using leaflet as described here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

and customize your infowindow using CSS